# Dask dataframe error while reading from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, dask, dask-distributed

Here is the code that I am using to connect to hdfs and create dask dataframe.

```
Client(scheduler_host+":"+scheduler_port)
df=dd.read_csv("hdfs://hdfs_host/<path to csv on hdfs>")
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: /usr/lib/libhdfs3.so: undefined symbol: hdfsConcat
```

HADOOP Version: 2.5.1

Comment: You do not have the latest version of libhdfs3

Comment: @mdurant: I have latest version libhdfs3 available for Ubuntu trusty.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libhdfs3 libhdfs3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libhdfs3 is already the newest version.
libhdfs3-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.

Comment: I cannot say how recent libhdfs3 is in your APT repo (you could check the version); I would normally recommend installation with conda.

Comment: I'll look into making version-agnostic code, but I am trying to iron out other build issues in libhdfs3 at the moment.